# How can extract images from pdf file using itext library in my android application

Tags: android

I want to extract images from pdf file using itext library where i put my pdf files in asset folder on android application and display these images in android using itext library.

Comment: No, I don't understand how can i do that

I searched more and more but i can't reach to anything

Comment: Try to use the answer I've given you. Tick if you feel its right. BUT it'll only save to the SD Card. Also next time try doing some code or presenting some research. Otherwise you'll find your questions negatively received

Comment: Screen Capture, GIMP, Cut, Paste, Autocrop to image, Export to Png, save with small letters as name, no special charaters in name, to drawable folder. Done. Oh yeah, this is off topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`iText` is a java library so it can be used in android.

Can you save to the assets folder. **NO**. Its read Only

Instead try saving to SD Card.

Please have a look at https://github.com/itext/i7js-samples/tree/develop/publications/book/src/test/java/com/itextpdf/samples/book/part4/chapter15
esp. files: Listing_15_30/31*.java
they should teach you how to extract images in iText

To customize for android

```
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.ImageRenderInfo;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.PdfImageObject;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.RenderListener;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.TextRenderInfo;

public class MyImageRenderListener implements RenderListener {

/** The new document to which we've added a border rectangle. */
protected String path = "";

/**
 * Creates a RenderListener that will look for images.
 */
public MyImageRenderListener(String path) {
    this.path = path;
}

/**
 * @see com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.RenderListener#beginTextBlock()
 */
public void beginTextBlock() {
}

/**
 * @see com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.RenderListener#endTextBlock()
 */
public void endTextBlock() {
}

/**
 * @see com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.RenderListener#renderImage(
 *     com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.ImageRenderInfo)
 */
public void renderImage(ImageRenderInfo renderInfo) {
    try {
        String filename;
        FileOutputStream os;
        PdfImageObject image = renderInfo.getImage();
        if (image == null) return;
        filename = String.format(path, renderInfo.getRef().getNumber(), image.getFileType());
        os = new FileOutputStream(filename);
        os.write(image.getImageAsBytes());
        os.flush();
        os.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}


   public void renderText(TextRenderInfo renderInfo) {
   }
}
```