# ImageRenderInfo Using in Android with iText Library

Tags: android, image, pdf, android-studio, itext

I can get texts from pdf with itext library in Android . This is the my code for it .

```
    MyFilePath = "/sdcard/" + fname + ".pdf";"

    for (int i = 1; i <= reader.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
            strategy = parser.processContent(i, new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy());

            strW.write(strategy.getResultantText());

        }
```

Also i want to get images and i want to save images to a folder. Then i found this ; [in top answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14120748/how-can-extract-images-from-pdf-file-using-itext-library-in-my-android-applicati)

I do not how to work this method. How can i use ImageRenderInfo ?

Comment: Good question. Here is someones' project on github, where he use ImageRenderInfo https://github.com/sunrenjie/itext/tree/b04ff17e0dc2d83dda93c77f09c6af56b29c7652/sandbox/src/main/java/javaone/edition14/part4/helper

Comment: Thank you for comment. But it some complicated . I did not understand.