# How to Extract Images from a PDF Form with iText

Tags: java, forms, pdf, itext, itext7

This article ([How to extract images from a PDF with iText in the correct order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7007917/how-to-extract-images-from-a-pdf-with-itext-in-the-correct-order)) explains how to pull images from a regular PDF file. I need to extract an image that a user has entered into a PDF *form field*.

I use iText 7. I can access the form fields in iText with code like this:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(new FileInputStream(new ClassPathResource("myFile.pdf").getFile()));
PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument(reader);
PdfAcroForm acroForm = PdfAcroForm.getAcroForm(document, false);
Map<String, PdfFormField> fields = acroForm.getFormFields();
PdfButtonFormField imageField = null;
PdfDictionary dictionary = null;
for (String fldName : fields.keySet()) {
      PdfFormField field = fields.get(fldName);
      if ("Image1_af_image".equals(fldName)) {
            imageField = (PdfButtonFormField)fields.get("Image1_af_image");
            dictionary = imageField.getPdfObject();
       }
}
```

where `Image1_af_imgage` is the default name of an image field in the form. Is it possible to extract an image stream from the `PdfButtonFormField` or its associated dictionary object?

Thank your for your very helpful response. I have incorporated your code as follows:

```
    public void iTextTest3() throws IOException {

        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(new FileInputStream(new ClassPathResource("templates/TestForm.pdf").getFile()));

        PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument(reader);
        String fieldname = "Image1_af_image";
        PdfAcroForm acroForm = PdfAcroForm.getAcroForm(document, false);

        PdfFormField imagefield = acroForm.getField(fieldname);
        // get the appearance dictionary
        PdfDictionary apDic = imagefield.getWidgets().get(0).getNormalAppearanceObject();
        // get the xobject resources
        PdfDictionary xObjDic = apDic.getAsDictionary(PdfName.Resources).getAsDictionary(PdfName.XObject);
        for (PdfName key : xObjDic.keySet()) {
            System.out.println(key);
            PdfStream s = xObjDic.getAsStream(key);
            // only process images
            if (PdfName.Image.equals(s.getAsName(PdfName.Subtype))) {  //*** code fails here ***
                PdfImageXObject pixo = new PdfImageXObject(s);
                byte[] imgbytes = pixo.getImageBytes();
                String ext = pixo.identifyImageFileExtension();

                // write the image to file
                String fileName = null;
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileName = key.toString().substring(1) + "." + ext);
                System.out.println(("image fileName: " + fileName));
                fos.write(imgbytes);
                fos.close();
            }
        }
        document.close();
    }
```

The code fails because `s.getAsName(PdfName.Subtype)` returns the value `"Form"`. I'm guessing that what I need to do is recurse into the XObject tree as you suggest in your post but am not sure just how to do that. I tried `xObjDic.getAsDictionary()` but am not sure what `PdfName` to pass in as an argument.

Comment: You mention iText without clarifying the version. According to your code I assume it's an iText 7 version?

Comment: Sorry, yes iText7.

Comment: @StephenSchultz I adapted my answer, based on your question edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The visual appearance of a button in PDF can be fully customized, with text, graphics and images. So, the image data could be stored in a slightly different way in different PDF documents. But generally speaking, the form field's *widget annotation* will have an *appearance stream*, which will have the image data as an *XObject* in its *Resources* dictionary.

Creating a PDF with a button with image for testing:

```java
String fieldname = "Image1_af_image";
PdfAcroForm form = PdfAcroForm.getAcroForm(pdfDoc, true);
PdfButtonFormField imagefield = PdfFormField.createButton(pdfDoc, new Rectangle(100, 100, 50, 50),
        PdfButtonFormField.FF_PUSH_BUTTON);
imagefield.setImage("button.png").setFieldName(fieldname);
form.addField(imagefield);
```

Getting the image data from a button:

```java
PdfAcroForm acroForm = PdfAcroForm.getAcroForm(pdfDoc, false);
PdfFormField imagefield = acroForm.getField(fieldname);
// get the appearance dictionary
PdfDictionary apDic = imagefield.getWidgets().get(0).getNormalAppearanceObject();
// get the xobject resources
PdfDictionary xObjDic = apDic.getAsDictionary(PdfName.Resources).getAsDictionary(PdfName.XObject);
for (PdfName key : xObjDic.keySet()) {
    System.out.println(key);
    PdfStream s = xObjDic.getAsStream(key);
    // only process images
    if (PdfName.Image.equals(s.getAsName(PdfName.Subtype))) {
        PdfImageXObject pixo = new PdfImageXObject(s);
        byte[] imgbytes = pixo.getImageBytes();
        String ext = pixo.identifyImageFileExtension();
    
        // write the image to file
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(key.toString().substring(1) + "." + ext);
        fos.write(imgbytes);
        fos.close();
    }
}
```

You can use a PDF object viewer, such as [iText RUPS](https://github.com/itext/i7j-rups) or Adobe Acrobat's built-in "Browse Internal PDF Structure", to inspect the exact structure of your PDF document and find out where the image data is stored.

[image: iText RUPS]

EDIT:

A more generic way of extracting the image data, in case it's in nested *Form XObjects*:

```java
PdfAcroForm acroForm = PdfAcroForm.getAcroForm(pdfDoc, false);
PdfFormField imagefield = acroForm.getField(fieldname);
// get the appearance dictionary
PdfDictionary apDic = imagefield.getWidgets().get(0).getNormalAppearanceObject();
// get the xobject resources
PdfDictionary xObjDic = apDic.getAsDictionary(PdfName.Resources).getAsDictionary(PdfName.XObject);
extractImagesFromXObj(xObjDic);
```

```java
public void extractImagesFromXObj(PdfDictionary xObjDic) throws IOException {
    for (PdfName key : xObjDic.keySet()) {
        System.out.println(key);
        PdfStream s = xObjDic.getAsStream(key);
        PdfName subType = s.getAsName(PdfName.Subtype);
        // only process images
        if (PdfName.Image.equals(subType)) {
            PdfImageXObject pixo = new PdfImageXObject(s);
            byte[] imgbytes = pixo.getImageBytes();
            String ext = pixo.identifyImageFileExtension();

            // write the image to file
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(key.toString().substring(1) + "." + ext);
            fos.write(imgbytes);
            fos.close();
        }
        // process nested XObject dictionaries recursively
        else if (PdfName.Form.equals(subType)) {
            PdfDictionary nestedXObjDic = s.getAsDictionary(PdfName.Resources).getAsDictionary(PdfName.XObject);
            extractImagesFromXObj(nestedXObjDic);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Depending on the PDF creation software the exact structure of the image differs, the image XObjects might not be immediate resources of the normal appearance stream but instead of a nested form XObject. Thus, in general one also has to recurse into the form XObjects of the appearance stream and look for image XObjects there, too.

Comment: Indeed, @mkl. I didn't want to complicate my initial answer with that more generic approach. But based on your comment and the edit that was made to the question, I have added some sample code to traverse the nested dictionaries.

Comment: This is brilliant--works exactly as you described and precisely what I needed--thanks! (I see that what I was missing was to iterate over xObjDic.keyset(). Always nice to learn a new trick!).

Comment: @StephenSchultz, if this solved your problem, please consider accepting the answer [1](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) [3](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/)

Comment: When I attempt to set the image programmatically using code supplied in the initial answer to my post I get this exception: com.itextpdf.kernel.PdfException: There is no associate PdfWriter for making indirects. at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfObject.makeIndirect(PdfObject.java:229. I'm interpreting "button.png" in the code as a resource flle name. Have tried a name relative to the application's path as well as supplying an absolute path.

Comment: After posting this comment I realized that I had indeed failed to configure a reader for this document. That done, the code executes!